# Why does my code not return the Max value of N?

Tags: java, max

The output is some huge number. I have tried about 10 different variations of the code. I understand that the biggest issue is I am not comprehending correctly. I am trying to self teach. This problem has me completely stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package com.codegym.task.task05.task0532;
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import java.io.*;

/* 
Task about algorithms
Write a program that:
1. reads a number N (must be greater than 0) from the console
2. reads N numbers from the console
3. Displays the maximum of the N entered numbers.


Requirements:
1. The program should read the numbers from the keyboard.
2. The program must display a number on the screen.
3. The class must have a public static void main method.
4. Don't add new methods to the Solution class.
5. The program should display the maximum of the N entered numbers.
6. The program should not display anything if N is less than or equal to 0.
*/

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int maximum = MAX_VALUE;
        int N = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());


        int i;
        int N2 = 0 ;
        for (i = 0; i != N; i++){
            N2 = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            maximum = N2;

        }
        System.out.println(maximum);

    }
}
```

Comment: If reading from the `console` then I suggest using `Scanner`

Comment: Check if N2 is greater than the maximum before assign it.

Comment: If you like an answer, you can upvote it. If you accept an answer, you can mark it accepted. That's the way to reward nice answers.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upvote it says. New to the site. How would I accept the answer? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect, and overwrites the maximum at each iteration without actually checking the value.  The logic you want is to start off at the `MIN_VALUE` of `Integer`, and assign a new maximum at each incoming value, should it be greater than the previous maximum.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int maximum = MIN_VALUE;
int N = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

for (int i=0; i < N; i++){
    int N2 = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    if (N2 > maximum) {
        maximum = N2;
    }
}
System.out.println(maximum);
```

Note: There is one subtle but unlikely edge case here.  Should the user enter `N = 0` for the number of inputs, the maximum reported would be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  This is somewhat meaningless, but is an artifact of the logic being used above.

Comment: Loop is not correct because of `i != N` (*edited*). Also, op is importing everything from `Integer` so you could use `parseInt` (and the [`max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#max-int-int-) function) without the class name.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Not true.  The loop would in fact have been entered, but you're right to point this out, and the condition should be `i < N`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this?

```
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import java.io.*;

/* 
Task about algorithms
Write a program that:
1. reads a number N (must be greater than 0) from the console
2. reads N numbers from the console
3. Displays the maximum of the N entered numbers.


Requirements:
1. The program should read the numbers from the keyboard.
2. The program must display a number on the screen.
3. The class must have a public static void main method.
4. Don't add new methods to the Solution class.
5. The program should display the maximum of the N entered numbers.
6. The program should not display anything if N is less than or equal to 0.
*/

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int N = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());


        int i;
        int N2 = 0 ;
        for (i = 0; i != N; i++){
            N2 = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            maximum = Math.max(N2,maximum);

        }
        System.out.println(maximum);
    }
}
```

The idea here is to set the value of maximum initially as a very *small* value so that we can compare and get the highest value from the set of values. At each iteration, a new number is read and compared with the existing value of maximum. If it is higher than `maximum`, it replaces maximum.

Here's what I tried as the input

```
5
4
8
9
1
2
```

Output

```
9
```

5 is the number of integers we enter, so initially lets assume a very small value for `maximum` (-2134). When it sees the first value (4), compares it with the current maximum (4>-2134), it assigns the value of `maximum` as 4. The iteration continues and the maximum value is 9, on comparing with values 1 and 2, the value of maximum remains unchanged.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Just editied the solution, it belongs to Math, you can replace it by Math.max without any additional imports

Comment: OP imports `java.lang.Integer.*` (so [`max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#max-int-int-) was fine).

Comment: Thank you. I had not used the Math.max () before!

Answer (score 0):

The value assigned to `maximum` is overwritten by every new input value parsed in from the reader at each iteration:

```java
int i;
int N2 = 0 ;
for (i = 0; i != N; i++){
    N2 = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    maximum = N2; // overwrites maximum with the newly parsed int

}
```

What you need is a way to keep track of the maximum number on each iteration by comparing with the last known maximum; starting off with the minimum value of integer as the maximum.

```java
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import java.io.*;

/* 
Task about algorithms
Write a program that:
1. reads a number N (must be greater than 0) from the console
2. reads N numbers from the console
3. Displays the maximum of the N entered numbers.


Requirements:
1. The program should read the numbers from the keyboard.
2. The program must display a number on the screen.
3. The class must have a public static void main method.
4. Don't add new methods to the Solution class.
5. The program should display the maximum of the N entered numbers.
6. The program should not display anything if N is less than or equal to 0.
*/

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        if (N < 1) {
            return; // covers requirement 6. The program should not display anything if N is less than or equal to 0.
        }


        int maximum = MIN_VALUE; // start off with the min value of integer as max value
        int i;
        int N2;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
            N2 = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            maximum = Math.max(N2, maximum);

        }
        System.out.println(maximum);
    }
}
```